# extract class name with maximum score from a json output using python

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, visual-recognition

I have a sample output of one of my codes. Here I want to extract the class name with maximum score. I can set the threshold value to collect the class name greater than the threshold value. But it's not helping to solve the problem.

```
 "classes": [
        {

          "score": 0.059986,
          "class": "box"
        },
        {
          "score": 0.0442621,
          "class": "Duster"
        },
        {
          "score": 0.931077,
          "class": "Multimeter"
        },
        {
          "score": 0.203139,
          "class": "sellotape"
        }
      ],
```

Please help to to write a python script to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
all_classes = {"classes": [
    {
      "score": 0.059986,
      "class": "box"
    },
    {
      "score": 0.0442621,
      "class": "Duster"
    },
    {
      "score": 0.931077,
      "class": "Multimeter"
    },
    {
      "score": 0.203139,
      "class": "sellotape"
    }
  ]}

print max(all_classes['classes'], key=lambda x: x["score"])

{'score': 0.931077, 'class': 'Multimeter'}
```